# Removing certain HTML tags using Regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE library to edit HTML which returns something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
... Your HTML ...
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to strip out the doctype, html, head and body tags so it will be

```
... Your HTML ...
```

Here is the function I am using.

```
function stripHTML(html) {
    return str.replace(/<(\/?|\!?)(DOCTYPE html|html|head|body)>/, ""); 
}
```

This only removes `<!DOCTYPE html>` from the string.

If there's an even easier way to do this, please point me in the right direction. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function stripHTML(html) {
     return str.replace(/<(\/?|\!?)(DOCTYPE html|html|head|body)>/g, ""); 
}
```

You need a global modifier to get all cases
http://regex101.com/r/aA1vL0

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
return str.replace(/<(\/?|\!?)(DOCTYPE html|html|head|body)>/g, "");
```

You don't have the `g` global flag so it's only replacing the first element it matched.

Answer (score 0):

Problem that \r\n symbols are not match your expression.
You can use this expression to strip all you want:

```
function stripHTML(html) {
      return str.replace(/(<![\w\W]*<body>|(<\/body>\W*<\/html>))/gmi, ""); 
}
```